# How to capture date out in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, state-machine-workflow

I have a requirement to capture `date in` and `date out`. `date in` is when the task is created. `date out` is when the task has been completed and assigned to a new checker. `date in` I can just set the default value to today's date in list settings but how can I set the `date out` In list settings or programatically in state machine workflow? I know there's a way to set the `date in` from state machine workflow which is by using startdate

```
createtask1_TaskProperties1.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Is there a similar way to set the date for `date out`?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with State machine workflow but may be you can use TaskProperties.DueDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5.0);

Let me know does it help or not ?

Thanks

Comment: but isnt this just going to add 5 days to the today's value? not actually capture the date when the task is completed?

Comment: is it possible to even set date completed? if not let me know? this is just a requirement from my boss and im not even programmer thus has limited knowledge on this

Comment: If a due date is specified then it is availble otherwise not  please find this link 

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/use-a-three-state-workflow-HA010154431.aspx